# Sending wmplayer to Hidden Icons, in the background

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, windows-media-player

Is there anyway to send windows media player to taskbar menu, in the Hidden Icons part like kmplayer?

I want to play musics in the background.

[image]

[image]

the wonderful icon doesn't work for me:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I find The Wonderful Icon (http://www.TheWonderfulIcon.Com) indispensable on XP. Apparently it needs updating, and some of the features don't work on later Windows, but if you're lucky the ones you want will work.

The features that will interest you are *Hide Window* and *Minimise to Tray*.

Let us know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Beside The Wonderful Icon there are few more apps that enable you to send almost any application to tray.
e.g.:

- AllToTray: http://download.cnet.com/AllToTray/3000-2072_4-10069128.html
- SendTray: https://github.com/renatosilva/winutils
- RBTray: http://rbtray.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, I'll bear them in mind when I am eventually forced away from XP.